# if logic breaks when calculating time over multiple days

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code below - yes, ugly. I am learning python. It works when the start/end dates are both the same day.

When start = 2017,6,15 6:00 & end = 2017,6,16 6:00
The if statement that gets applied is if start < 6am. Can someone explain why? It does recognize that 1 day is the duration.

from datetime import datetime, date, time

```
def babysitting():

    (st_yr,st_mon,st_day) = [int(s) for s in input("Enter the start date in the format: YYYY,M,D: ").split(',')]
    (st_hr,st_min) = [int(s) for s in input("Enter the start time in 24hr format -> HH:MM: ").split(":")]
    (e_yr,e_mon,e_day) = [int(s) for s in input("Enter the end date in the format: YYYY,M,D: ").split(',')]
    (e_hr,e_min) = [int(s) for s in input("Enter the end time in 24hr format -> HH:MM: ").split(":")]

    st_date = date(st_yr,st_mon,st_day)
    st_time = time(st_hr,st_min)
    end_date= date(e_yr,e_mon,e_day)
    end_time = time(e_hr,e_min)

    start = datetime.combine(st_date,st_time)
    end = datetime.combine(end_date,end_time)

    ninePM = datetime.combine(end_date, time(21,00))
    sixAM = datetime.combine(end_date, time(6,00))

    if start >= sixAM:
        if end <= ninePM:
            normal_rate_duration = end - start
            normal_rate_seconds = normal_rate_duration.total_seconds()
            normal_rate_billing = round(((normal_rate_seconds / 60) / 60) * 2.5,2)
            print("Cost for babysitting is: $", normal_rate_billing)

        elif end > ninePM:
            normal_rate_duration = ninePM - start
            reduced_rate_pm_duration = end - ninePM
            normal_rate_seconds = normal_rate_duration.total_seconds()
            normal_rate_billing = round(((normal_rate_seconds / 60) / 60) * 2.5,2)
            reduced_rate_pm_seconds = reduced_rate_pm_duration.total_seconds()
            reduced_rate_pm_billing = round(((reduced_rate_pm_seconds / 60) / 60) * 1.75,2)
            print("Cost for babysitting is: $", normal_rate_billing + reduced_rate_pm_billing)

    if start < sixAM:
        if end <= ninePM:
            reduced_rate_am_duration = sixAM - start
            reduced_rate_am_seconds = reduced_rate_am_duration.total_seconds()
            reduced_rate_am_billing = round(((reduced_rate_am_seconds / 60) / 60) * 1.75,2)
            normal_rate_duration = end - sixAM
            normal_rate_seconds = normal_rate_duration.total_seconds()
            normal_rate_billing = round(((normal_rate_seconds / 60) / 60) * 2.5,2)
            print("Cost for babysitting is: $", normal_rate_billing + reduced_rate_am_billing)
        elif end > ninePM:
            reduced_rate_am_duration = sixAM - start
            reduced_rate_am_seconds = reduced_rate_am_duration.total_seconds()
            reduced_rate_am_billing = round(((reduced_rate_am_seconds / 60) / 60) * 1.75,2)
            normal_rate_duration = ninePM - sixAM
            normal_rate_seconds = normal_rate_duration.total_seconds()
            normal_rate_billing = round(((normal_rate_seconds / 60) / 60) * 2.5,2)
            reduced_rate_pm_duration = end - ninePM
            reduced_rate_pm_seconds = reduced_rate_pm_duration.total_seconds()
            reduced_rate_pm_billing =round(((reduced_rate_pm_seconds / 60) / 60) * 1.75,2)
            print("Cost for babysitting is: $", normal_rate_billing + reduced_rate_am_billing + reduced_rate_pm_billing)

babysitting()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `if` checks whether or not the start time was earlier than 6am on the end date, which of course it will be (it's some time the day before or something like that). you need to check if `st_time` is earlier than 6am (regardless of date, or on the `st_date` date).

Comment: My  if starts here: 'if start >= sixAM:'

Comment: `sixAM` is 6am on the end date. obviously, if your start time is the day before, it's also before `sixAM`.
or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: It is probably I that am misunderstanding. Lets say start time is 6am Tues and End time is 6am Wed. The If statement getting applied is start < 6am. This is where I am stuck. Do not understand why start >= 6am is not getting applied.

Comment: it's because your 6am variable (i.e. `sixAM`) is defined as 6am on the end date rught before all the if block starts.

the line is `sixAM = datetime.combine(end_date, time(6,00))`